# How to pickup a color from dojox/widget/ColorPicker onChange?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

I need to get selected color in `dojox/widget/ColorPicker` when user choose one in the color palette.

I am trying several solutions but with no success.

Notes: I need to set up this event listener with a programmatic declaration.

Any idea how to get the color value `onChange`?

Live example:
http://jsbin.com/venaconuwo/edit?html,output

```
var myColorPicker = new ColorPicker({
                animatePoint: false,
                showHsv: true,
                showRgb: true,
            }, 'myColorPicker');
            myColorPicker.onChange(function (color) {
                console.log(color);
            });
            myColorPicker.on('change', function (color) {
                console.log(color);
            });
            myColorPicker.on('onChange', function (color) {
                console.log(color);
            });
            aspect.after('myColorPicker', 'onChange', function (color) {
                console.log('after', color);
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use onChange when

1. Change your onChange to look like

   myColorPicker.onChange=function (color) {
                   console.log(color);
               };
2. Not sure why, but onChange is only fired when you have animatePoint to true

Comment: You are right, it is probably a bug in the ColorPicker. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
on(myColorPicker, "mouseUp", function(evt) {
    console.log(myColorPicker.get("value"))
})
```

updated [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/hociqoxupu/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your hack.... but unfortunately I need to have it even onChange. Any other ideas?